# Strange behavior of footer in Interactive grid in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an interactive grid with over 2000 records. I have set the number of records as 100. My pagination type is : Page and Show total row count is set to 'Yes'.

[image]

Now when I click on the arrow in the footer to go to next set of 100 rows,it shows a strange behaviour. for couple of next's it works fine i.e shows 1-100 of 2118 , 101-200 of 2118 and so on. But then suddenly when it reaches 1000  it gives weird numbering like 1001-1191 of 2118, 1192-1291 of 2118 and so on. If I go back to the previous page , the numbering is again distorted.

Can somebody please suggest what is the problem here.

Comment: Hi.. Not able to find a solution for this yet. Highly appreciate if somebody can help me with this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to resolve the issue. The issue was that I had a column called user_name which I had set as primary key. But actually there were multiple records for usernames.It was not unique. Then I had picked up another column with unique distinct values as primary key and after that the issue was resolved.

Hope this helps somebody!